# Which table used for Inventory Valuation Report?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I need to be able to access the data used by the Inventory Valuation report, on which the **historic** stock quantities are shown.

Do you know where this report is looking for info?

--FTR We decided to do a scheduled log entry in the meanwhile.

Comment: Do have a specific field(s) in mind?

Comment: I just need the available qty

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would get that information. Hopefully this gives you some ideas.

Search: Transaction

Criteria: Type = Purchase Order and Item Fulfullment

Results: 
 
-Item 
-Date 
-Quantity 
-Quantity Fulfilled

Depending on how you want your data to look, you can also `GROUP` by the items and `SUM` the quantity fields. You could create a customer formula that would `SUM` the items received, but then subtracts the items fulfilled and then maybe create a custom date field and `GROUP` by the month. Lots of ways to make the output look better with the SQL Expressions.

Comment: I think that would show the stock variations rather than the qty at the required period.